# I want to throw error when run yarn start if i had many eslint error

Tags: eslint, yarnpkg

I'm newbie with code, so I want to throw error when run yarn start if i had many eslint error ? Some one can help me? But when i had many eslint error so app was running.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to so. I don't think you can do such a thing because of how you define many 10 or 1000. but you can add this to your command so eslint fix as many as problems possible.

```
lint -- --fix
```

if you want to run it separately you can use

```
 run lint -- --fix
```